# Empty array when passing it into a component (Input)

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I create multiple array with the result of a request API. Here is my method of a component which is called when pressing a button.

```
ngOnInit() {


  // GetListeAnomalies(start_date : string, end_date : string) -> return an array
  this.servicePS.getListeAnomalies("2019-10-08", "2019-10-08").then(
    (anomalies : any) => {

      for (let anomalie of anomalies){

        switch (anomalie.type_anomalie) {

          case "erreur_deltaT_recurrent": {
            this.tab_delta_T_recurrent.push(anomalie);
            break;
          }


          case "erreur_absence_emission": {
            this.tab_absence_emission.push(anomalie);
            break;
          }

          case "erreur_delta_T_trop_grand":{
            this.tab_deltaT_trop_grand.push(anomalie);
            break;
          }

          case "erreur_capteur_batterie_faible":{
            this.tab_capteur_batterie_faible.push(anomalie);
            break;
          }

          case "erreur_device_a_remplacer_grande_derive":{
            this.tab_device_a_remplacer_grande_derive.push(anomalie);
            break;
          }

          default: {
            this.tab_other.push(anomalie)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Then, I want to pass these arrays in my component named 'tableau-anomalies'. So I use this line :

```
<app-tableau-anomalies [tabValeurs]="tab_delta_T_recurrent"></app-tableau-anomalies>
```

In my component, I try to use the Input value but this one is not correctly initialized. Look at my component's code (and my comments)

```
export class TableauAnomaliesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() tabValeurs: any;  

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.tabValeurs.length); //Return 0
    console.log(this.tabValeurs); //Return CORRECTLY my array with my data.

    for (let anomalie in this.tabValeurs){
      console.log(anomalie);  //This iteration is not called --> no return, not even 'undefined' is written in the console.
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT :** Sorry, I forgot to write this part of my code... I tried with "onChanges" too.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

      if (changes.tabValeurs){

        console.log(this.tabValeurs.length); //Return 0

        for (let anomalie of this.tabValeurs){
          console.log(anomalie);//This iteration is not called --> no return, not even 'undefined' is written in the console.
        }
      }   
  }
```

I think there is a solution with something like Promise or Subscribe ? But I don't know how to use it in my case...
So can you help me ? Have you got any idea of a solution ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try using map instead of for ?

Comment: I don't know how to use it.. can you explain please ?

Comment: I did in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

You should log your Input value in the OnChanges life cycle since you can't on the OnInit life cycle.

```
export class TableauAnomaliesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

   ...

   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
      // Here
   }

   ...
}
```

And try to log the changes parameter and see what you have inside.

Using map instead of for would be better as well.

On the parent

```
this.servicePS.getListeAnomalies("2019-10-08", "2019-10-08").then(
(anomalies : any) => {
   anomalies.forEach(anomalie => {
      ...
   })
}
```

On the child

```
this.tabValeurs.forEach(anomalie => { console.log(anomalie) })
```

You should check more in [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write this part of my code... I tried with "onChanges" too. I edited my question

Comment: Did you try with the map or forEach function ? (edit on my post)

Comment: That's not working anymore, because my array (this.tabValeurs) is undefined

Comment: You did it in the ngOnChanges ?

Comment: Use `map` along with `initialize input`

Answer (score 0):

Look into [angular life cycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). You are trying to to access `tabValeurs` in `OnInit` life cycle. Here `tabValeurs` is not populated yet. You can use `OnChanges` to look for changes in your inputs and do something based on that.

**Minimum Example:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() tabValeurs: any[] = [];

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.tabValeurs) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

And it is a good idea to initialize `@Input` type array variables as empty array when declaring. That way you can avoid null checks in `html`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write this part of my code... I tried with "onChanges" too. I edited my question.

Comment: I tried your idea : initialize input, but that not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

the bindings are only updated when there is a change detection. So the array itself not changed I'm think the solution is intercepting @Input changes with getter and setter

```
@Input() set tabValeurs (val: any) {
 this._tabValeurs = val;
}

_tabValeurs: any;
```

Comment: When I try it, I've got an undefined value

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I finally found the solve :

I used a boolean :

```
<app-tableau-anomalies *ngIf="isDataAvailable" [tabValeurs]="tab_delta_T_recurrent"></app-tableau-anomalies>
```

And this is my ts file of my parent component

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.servicePS.getListeAnomalies("2019-10-08", "2019-10-08").then(
      (anomalies : any) => {

        for (let anomalie of anomalies){
         ...
        }
      }
    ).then( 
      () => this.isDataAvailable = true);
  }
```

Comment: Oh ! You can check async pipe in that case